# Pi 3 B as wi-fi usb stick for my TB

Tags: usb, storage

I have a Raspberry PI 3 B + external 300 GB HDD. What I want is, to use the PI as a simple USB stick/storage for my TV.

Also, I want to access the device over wi-fi/samba from my computer, to upload/delete media files.

I have installed the Raspbian Stretch, mounted the external hdd under `/mnt/hdd/`.

But when I plug the Raspberry into my TV, nothing happens.

Comment: `use the PI as a simple USB stick` .. do you have it configured that way?

Comment: No. I have no ideea how to make this dir `/mnt/hdd` (and knly this) accessible by my TV

Comment: why don't you just plug the HDD into the TV?  .... otherwise, you will have to program the RPi to emulate a flash drive. this would probably require additional hardware also, since the TV and the RPi are both USB masters

Comment: Because I am lazy and I don't want to plug/unplug the hdd 4 times per day :D Any ideea how to emulate RPI as flash drive?

Comment: i would have to research that .... you can do the same .... how exactly are you connecting the RPi to the TV? .... you could also get another drive

Comment: does the TV have a LAN connection?

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/kodi/README.md ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kodi on it.

Or if you just want to use kodi on it you can get a different os like LibreELEC which is the bare minimum you need for kodi and xmbc types or what I like to do is get Recalbox os and Auto start kodi and when i want to play games I exit Kodi and it has a terminal.

Kodi lets you stream from your network with ease or connect to streaming services. You can also use samba if you want or control it over ssh or just load files from your hdd in a very simple screen.